# Passing boolean model property with AJAX at runtime

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to pass a property of my model to an AJAX form but since the bool resolves as "true/false" I'm encountering problems.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Projects/SearchTable2',
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        sub_num: @Model.SubmissionNumber,
        read_only: @Model.ReadOnly,
    }
});
```

`Model.ReadOnly` resolves to either true or false which throws an `Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined` when I try to execute the code. Is there a workaround for this, or another way I can pass the variable to the Controller method?

Comment: change @Model.ReadOnly to @Model.ReadOnly.ToLower()

Comment: @MajidParvin there is no member function `.ToLower()` for type bool

Comment: I mean @Model.ReadOnly.ToString().ToLower() .

Comment: @MajidParvin great, that worked. Could you make it an answer to the question so I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: @MajidParvin I need to wait 5 minutes and then I will. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @MajidParvin no sorry the 5 minutes just passed and I had forgotten! Just accepted your answer :) thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Model.ReadOnly` render as a `Capital  Boolean (True)` and JavaScript has no idea about it, so just change your code to it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Projects/SearchTable2',
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        sub_num: @Model.SubmissionNumber,
        read_only: @Model.ReadOnly.ToString().ToLower(),
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When razor executes the code in the view, It will output the below code to the browser

```
read_only: True,
```

Assuming `@Model.ReadOnly` returns boolean true.

In C# boolean value is either `True` or `False`, but in js, it is lower case `true` or `false`

So when browser's javascript framework try to execute this code, It does not treat `True` as `true`. It thinks True is a js variable. But since we did not define it earlier, we are getting the "True is not defined" error!

What you have to do is, convert the boolean value produced by C# code to something which js understands. Call `ToString()` and call `ToLower`  which will convert `True` to `true`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Projects/SearchTable2',
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        sub_num: @Model.SubmissionNumber,
        read_only: @Model.ReadOnly.ToString().ToLower(),
    }
});
```